# Get single item from array through destructuring

Tags: javascript

We have `prefer-destructuring` enabled in our ESLint rules and it is giving me an error on the line of code below, but I have no idea how to use destructuring in this particular case.

```
modifiedResults = partition[1];
```

So far I have tried:

```
[, modifiedResults, ] = partition;
[, modifiedResults, ...] = partition;
[, modifiedResults, ...rest] = partition;
```

None of these work, and for the last one it is telling me that `rest` is not defined, which is fair enough as I was intending it as a throw away variable.

Any ideas would appreciated...

Comment: *"None of these work"* what does that mean? How does it not work? What do you expect, what happens, what's the error *(message)*? The first and the last one should both work. *"the last one it is telling me that `rest` is not defined"* well, your snippet doesn't declare any variable `rest`. is it just assigning it a value to it, assuming that the variable already exists. If the variable is not declared and you're in strict mode, this will throw an error, if you're not, shame on you ;) no seriously, `"use strict"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first try should work and can be simplified as

```
let [, modifiedResults] = partition;
```

I did try it and it works, if it doesn't work it should be related to something else IMO

Comment: You are absolutely right... I have no idea why it did not work for me the first time round...

Comment: if that syntax results a little weird  then you can use _ placeholder instead an empty value.   :   

let [_,  modifiedResults] = partition;

Answer (score 4):

You could use an object with index and rename that property to the wanted.

```js
var partition = [1, 42, 1000],
    { 1: modifiedResults } = partition;
    
console.log(modifiedResults);
```

Comment: This works too but I will go for the other answer in lieu of its briefness.